# JFlashPlayer: how to generate ActionScript event

Tags: java, flash, actionscript, djnativeswing

Using the DJNativeSwing `JFlashPlayer`, I need to intercept in Java a simple event generated by flash / actionscript.

Adding the Java listener seems obvious:

```
JFLashPlayer flashPlayer = new JFlashPlayer();
flashPlayer.addFlashPlayerListener(this);
(...)

@Override
public void commandReceived(FlashPlayerCommandEvent e) {
   System.out.println("Received flash command:"+e.getCommand());
}
```

But I couldn't find any documentation on how to generate a flash / actionscript event that would be catched by the listener.

Any idea / hint would be more than welcome !
Thx,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

this is the way how we say to flash to give us a chance to run something when some event happened and finished: (put this at the end of your event in your class)

```
edispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
```

and this is how we use that point to run sth else where you have called and used the class:

```
class.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, your_Function);
your_Function(e:Event):void
{
    do my job
}
```